# android studio Failed to query the value of property 'applicationId'

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

hello little question i have a problem when i build the graddle i have this error and i don't know how to fix it do you know what it was? the graddle comes from a feature ^^

error:

```
Execution failed for task ':features:module_astronomie:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests'.
 Failed to calculate the value of task ':features:module_astronomie:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests' property 'applicationId'.
   Failed to query the value of property 'applicationId'.
     Collection has more than one element.
```

my graddle file:

```java
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "descartes.info.l3ag2.descartes.info.l3ak2.eyetrek"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 6
        versionName "6.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner 'androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
        renderscriptTargetApi 28 //must match target sdk and build tools
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        intermediaire {
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    buildToolsVersion = '28.0.3'
}

dependencies{}
```

my AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="org.opencv"
    android:versionCode="5"
    android:versionName="0.5.1.1 eyetrek_dev"
    >
</manifest>
```

Comment: Post your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: it's done hoping it’ll help you ^^

Comment: Why your is your package="org.opencv" but your applicationId "descartes.info... " ? That could be right or wrong depending if you refactored the app

Comment: hum i make a mistake ^^

Comment: facing exactly same problem

Comment: ARE YOU USING DYNAMIC MODULE?

Comment: yes @NitinPrakash but i found solution module doesn't have application id just remove this line and it's fine ^^

Comment: @Duskley but for me, I am using product flavours in the base Module, solution is I have to declare the same product flavours in the dynamic module also

Comment: I am facing the same issue and all the above mention solutions did not worked for me!!